# retrieve existing Hbase table name programmatically

Tags: java, hbase

Is there any way to retrieve existing  Hbase table name with java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [HBaseAdmin.listTables](http://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#listTables())